# String Number Regex Issue

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to build regex for the following examples:
football team name|Percentage value (without the pipe)
the percentage value can contain 1 or 2 numbers and ends with %
the issue is when the team name ends with numbers like:
schalke 04
so the string will be: schalke 041% or schalke 0420%
and i need to extract the team name and the percentage value.
the football team name can be any of the teams in Europe.

what is the best regex solution to extract?
now i have something like his:
[A-Za-z 0-9']+([0-9]{1,2}%)
but if the string is schalke 0412%, after extraction i get schalke 041 and 2%.
i'm using C#.

Thanks.

Comment: What is static and what is dynamic (=can change) in this string?  What is the rule for matching `abc04`? Try `[A-Za-z ']+[0-9]{2}([0-9]{1,2}%)`

Comment: How about `abc04(1%|12%)` ?

Comment: i forgot to mention but it can be also abc12% (without 04), and the numbers can be anywhere in the name, like 4abc, ab4c, abc etc..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the static is only the % in the end

Comment: I think you forgot even more details. Please add all the requirements to the question. Maybe all you need is [`(?:04)?([0-9]{1,2}%)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a04%29%3f%28%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c2%7d%25%29&i=abc041%25%0d%0aabc0412%25%0d%0aabc12%25%0d%0aabc1%25%0d%0a0abc1%25%0d%0aab5c12%25)

Comment: A good way for asking questions (and coming up with answers) with regexes is to add a few examples of what should match and what shouldn't

Comment: _" if the string is abc0412%, after extraction i get abc041 and 2%."_ You should also show your code that returns the wrong result. It helps to understand the requirement and shows that you've tried it yourself

Comment: *the static is only the % in the end*. In that case, maybe just split the string by `%` and see what you can glean from the resulting array...

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for your comment, i'll add the code later today, i don't have it right now.

Comment: @EranMaymony: Sorry, you should be very specific about the requirement: *how can you determine why `1` should be in Group 2 and not `41` in `abc041%`*?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is exactly my problem, i can't know cause the name can contains any characters or numbers at least 1 length long and the percentage can be 1 or 2 numbers and there is no character between them.

Comment: Then how can you be sure that `41` is not valid result for the string in question?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  i can get somehow to the list of possible names that end with numbers, then define the regex again, or develop it without regex, a mechanism to check every character till i found the string in the list

Comment: @EranMaymony: Please update the question with these details - but add some concrete details, not just the comment above. We need to see the data you have and the logic to build a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, i updated the question

Comment: You need to have the list of the teams. Then, remove them from the string and you will only have the digits that are the percentage value (remove the `%` and here you are). No regex is necessary. Or, you may build a regex with `|` to remove team names (like `Regex.Replace(s, @"Team1|Team02", "")`)

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, i'll probably go on this way.

Comment: Just  make sure you replace beginning with the longest team name (sort the list first by length in descending order).

Answer (score -1):

You need lazy search for the number group before percentage group.
(added ? after +) It will make the group marked by ? less important and it will try to fullfill requirements of other groups first.

```
[A-Za-z 0-9']+?([0-9]{1,2}%)
```